# Android Firebase Realtime Database delete child node whose id is named by Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

But I don't want to hard code the last child's id.
Here I want to get id of specific node which is under "yaada" when clicked and then delete it.But I don't want to hard code the last child's id.

final DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("photos").child(photo_id).child("yaada").child("-M7YsqlH_EZdrbFzdg8y");
        database.removeValue();

Check the holder.delete.......

[here is my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8mNw.png)

Here is where I add comment in FirebaseMethods.class

```
public void addNewComment(final String node, final String mediaId, final String comment){

final String commentId = myRef.push().getKey();
final String dateAdded = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy ",Locale.getDefault()).format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
Query query = myRef.child(mActivity.getString(R.string.user_account_settings_node)).child(userID);
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        String userName = Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child(mActivity.getString(R.string.usernameField)).getValue()).toString();
        String profileImage = Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child(mActivity.getString(R.string.profilePhotoField)).getValue()).toString();

        Comment comment_model = new Comment(comment, dateAdded, userName, profileImage, 0);
        myRef.child(node).child(mediaId).child(mActivity.getString(R.string.fieldComments))
                .child(Objects.requireNonNull(commentId)).setValue(comment_model);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

Here is my CommentListAdapter Class;

```
   public class CommentListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Comment> {

        private Activity mContext;
        private int layoutResource;
        private long limit=20;
        private UtilityInterface utilityInterface;
        private FirebaseAuth mAuth;


        CommentListAdapter(@NonNull Activity context, int resource, ArrayList<Comment> comments) {
            super(context,resource,comments);
            mContext = context;
            layoutResource = resource;
            utilityInterface = (UtilityInterface)mContext;
        }

        private static class ViewHolder{

            ImageView profileImage;
            TextView comment;
            //TextView commentLike;
            TextView dateAdded;
            ImageView addLike;
            TextView commentReply;
        }




        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

            final ViewHolder holder;
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

            SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("pass_user_id", MODE_PRIVATE);
            final String user_id = prefs.getString("user_id", "");
            final String photo_id = prefs.getString("photo_id", "");


            if(convertView==null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(layoutResource, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.profileImage = convertView.findViewById(R.id.comment_profile);
                holder.comment = convertView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
                //holder.commentLike = convertView.findViewById(R.id.commentLike);
                holder.dateAdded = convertView.findViewById(R.id.date_added);
                holder.addLike = convertView.findViewById(R.id.comment_heart);
                holder.commentReply = convertView.findViewById(R.id.commentReply);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else {
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }


            final Comment commentData = getItem(position);


            //Setting profile image
            GlideImageLoader.loadImageWithOutTransition(mContext, Objects.requireNonNull(commentData).getProfile_image(),holder.profileImage);
            //Setting userName and comment
            final String userName = Objects.requireNonNull(commentData).getUser_name();
            SpannableStringBuilder str = new SpannableStringBuilder(userName+" "+commentData.getComment());
            str.setSpan(new android.text.style.StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 0, userName.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            holder.comment.setText(str);
            //Setting date
            holder.dateAdded.setText(commentData.getDate_added());

            holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
    //                if (user_id.equals(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid().toString())){
    //

                    final Intent mediaIntent = mContext.getIntent();
                    String photo_id = mediaIntent.getStringExtra("photo_id");
                    String user_id = mediaIntent.getStringExtra("user_id");

                    FirebaseDatabase fb_db_instance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

                    final DatabaseReference database = (DatabaseReference) FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("photos").child(photo_id).child(mContext.getString(R.string.fieldComment));
    //                DatabaseReference db_ref_Main = fb_db_instance.getReference(database.push().getKey());
                    database.removeValue();  

                }

            });



            return  convertView;
        }




    }
```

Comment: While using a ChildEventListener is the recommended way to read  [lists of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events) You can display them in the recyclerView. You can remove the item clicked from the recyclerView and database.

Comment: Are you showing the photos with a recyclerView? If yes add the adapter code. Add the database screenshot to your question not as a link.

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir Thanks for the answer. But still ChildEventlistener returns all the node id under "yaada" node. But I want to get only id of the clicked node.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you assign unique names to your child nodes under `yaada` and then you can easily get the id of that node and delete or do whatever you want. Here is how you can do it.

```
//Before pushing, assign a unique userId to each child node
String uniqueId= ( hash created using username and date_added);

FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference rootReference=firebaseDatabase.getReference();
DatabaseReference myRef = rootReference.child("photos").child(photo_id).child("yaada").child(uniqueId);
CommentClass newComment=new CommentClass(comment,commentLikes,date,profileImage,userName);
 myRef.setValue(newComment).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>()    {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
           //add your onComplete logic
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
           //add your onFailure logic

        }
    });
```

So, next time if you want to make any changes to that node, you just have to use the id of that node.

```
uniqueId.removeValue();
```

If you want to use the id provided by Firebase, then here is how you can do so:

```
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference rootReference=firebaseDatabase.getReference();
DatabaseReference myRef = rootReference.child("photos").child(photo_id).child("yaada");
CommentClass newComment=new CommentClass(comment,commentLikes,date,profileImage,userName);

String childId= myRef.push().getKey();
myRef.child(childId).setValue(newComment);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i have already added the comment and firebase has already pushed the id. now i wanted to delete data with that id. which is like...."M7YsqlH_EZdrbfzdg8y"..........

Comment: You can directly do so from the firebase console. And for next time, you can implement this.